# Building a sequence that alternates for odd numbers without using cases

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering, whether it is possible to build a sequence, that alternates for odd numbers, such as
$$a_n = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if} \ n = 4k+1, k\in \mathrm{N} \\
-1, & \text{if} \ n = 4k+3, k\in\mathrm{N}
\end{cases}$$ 
but without using cases.

An option would be $a_n = \sin(\frac{n}{2}\pi)$ but I wonder whether there is some kind of alternative, that would e.g. use something like $a_n = (-1)^{v(n)}$ where $v: \mathrm{N}\to\mathrm{N}, \ n \mapsto v(n)$.

The result for $a_n$ if $n$ ist even doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $$a_n=(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Try
$$
\frac{i^n-i^{-n}}{2i}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Other approaches are

$$a(n)=2 - n\mod 4$$

and

$$a(n)=(n+1)\mod 4 - 1$$